# Org babel: Use variable to set a figure caption

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

This is what I want to do:

In `some-file.org`:

```
* Table 1
#+NAME: table-1-title
Characteristcs of Data

#+BEGIN_SRC R :file table-1.svg :results output graphics file
  (
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))
    + geom_point()
  )
#+END_SRC

#+caption: > HERE I WANT TO USE THE table-1-title VAR DEFINED ABOVE <
#+attr_latex: :width 375px :placement [H]
#+RESULTS:
```

I want to use the `table-1-title` variable to set the caption. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is an Org construct (like `:var`) to do that.  You will likely need to use an Emacs Lisp variable, e.g. `(set (make-local-variable 'foo) "value")`.  I would define these in a separate `:noexport:` section within an elisp source block.  The difficulty is how to *eval* the variable on export.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use src babel blocks for org like the following:

```
* Table 1
#+NAME: table-1-title
Characteristcs of Data

#+BEGIN_SRC R :file table-1.svg :results output graphics file
  (
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))
    + geom_point()
  )
#+END_SRC

#+name: result-file
#+RESULTS:
table-1.svg

#+begin_src org :results replace :var title=table-1-title file=result-file
#+caption: $title
#+attr_latex: :width 375px :placement [H]
$file
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+caption: Characteristcs of Data
#+attr_latex: :width 375px :placement [H]
table-1.svg
```

Comment: Ok I got it now. I have never thought of using an org block before. Please vote for my question so I can vote for your answer. My reputation is too low...